# I propose we add a Vote-to-Close reason to handle licensing questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, scope

I would propose the following wording, or some variation there-of:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.  Questions on licensing should be referred to the vendor, and an answer obtained in writing from them.

Some sample questions that I've voted-to-close with this reason:

[MySQL licensing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28318/mysql-licensing)

[sql server license](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/sql-server-license)

[Help about Oracle licensing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61127/help-about-oracle-licensing)

[How to verify an oracle database license](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60054/how-to-verify-an-oracle-database-license)

Also, this proposed question contained within this meta-question about licensing being on-topic:  [Can I ask a question about ODBC driver and license?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/can-i-ask-a-question-about-odbc-driver-and-license)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need this instead of marking it as just plain old off topic?

Comment: Since there are possible legal ramifications to bad advice, having a discrete vote-to-close reason defined in the list would make it more obvious to closers what to use as the reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need a new close reason for this.

1. The volume of licensing questions doesn't justify it
2. Existing close reasons can be used (e.g. too localized/too broad/opinion-based)
3. A link to the relevant meta discussion is sufficient to provide context:
   [Are licensing questions within our scope?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/1192)

I just don't feel it is worth cluttering up the vote to close page for this specific case.

Comment: Perhaps adding a canonical question / answer like they have on Serverfault would be less intrusive (bad choice of wording but not sure how else to put it)?